# Can a gauge theory with $SU(2)_{left}*SU(2)_{additional}$ symmetry contain confinement?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, confinement

Consider a gauge theory with $SU(2)_{left}*SU(2)_{additional}$ symmetry.
By $additional$, I mean adding a new symmetry between an electron and a quark(like up quark and electron forming a doublet).

And $SU(2)_{left}$ is part of the total SM symmetries.

-Can such theory contain confinement?

-If yes what are the bound states of it?

---

The question was edited due to a mistake pointed out by @Prof.Legolasov.
Thanks

Comment: Explain the meaning and properties of the symbols you have written. They appear oddball if not meaningless.

Comment: I wish you could exactly point out the misunderstanding.
I try to explain
Consider the electroweak symmetry(apart from the $U(1)$) at first: $SU(2)_{leptonic, left}*SU(2)_{quark, left}$
The multiplication of two lie groups.
Then let's imagine that there's also a new symmetry between the leptonic sector and the quark sector. For instance another $SU(2)$ symmetry whose fundamental representation is a (quark, electron) doublet.
One can limit the new $SU(2)$ symmetry to left-handed fermions or more generally to a non-chiral representation. (chirally symmetric, just like massless standard QCD)

Comment: ? So the Ws connecting quark flavors are *different* than the Ws connecting leptons? And there are yet different Ws converting quarks to leptons? Do you appreciate what stringent experimental constraints for this prevail?

Comment: I finally understood the misunderstanding.
Do you agree that there're two doublets in SM? One doublet for the leptons and another one for the quarks. In fact we simply write only one $SU(2)_{left}$ since the W bosons coupling to both sectors are considered to be the same.
Just like the coupling of the same Higgs doublet to two different sectors of SM, namely: Leptons and Quarks but this time with different Yukawa couplings.

Comment: I just want to bold this point that the additional symmetry between an electron and a quark can naturally, for instance, result in the existence of a symmetry between a down quark and a ${neutrino}{electron}$
So I think adding a single new symmetry can't be very far from the mainstream physics!

Comment: @BastamTajik there is a single $SU(2)$, quarks and leptons are just in different irreducible blocks of the (reducible) representation of $SU(2)$ on Standard Model fermions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the point you made. I just correct the question.

Comment: Review SU(5) GUT.

Answer (score 0):

By the star I'm assuming you mean group product.

Yes you would be able to still have confinement. In the standard model, as far as I can tell, we REQUIRE confinement due to experimental observations. 
Confinement basically means any particle made of quarks need to be in a trivial representation of SU(3). So, if we had an SU(2) strong force instead, then we'd need to find the trivial representations of SU(2). We can do this using the young-tableau. I'm not sure how to write them out using Latex, so I'll just give the answer here if $\underline{2}$ is the defining representation of SU(2) then:

$\underline{2}\otimes\underline{2}=\underline{1}\oplus\underline{3}$

where the number is the dimension of that representation. The first representation in the decomposition is a trivial rep, so we can use it for a colourless combination of quarks (i.e for confinement). So for SU(2), we only need a minimum of two quarks for confinement, not 3. I also note here that the trivial rep is antisymmetric and the other is fully symmetric (this can easily be seen from their Young Tableau). Then we need to find the possible representations of the other two groups in the theoretical SM you gave. They're all SU(2) so their decomposition is the same as for the strong force. Our "baryon" will be of the form:
$Q^{ij \: ab \:\alpha\beta}$ where the i,j are indices for $SU(2)_{lepton}$, a,b indices for $SU(2)_{quark}$ and $\alpha,\beta$ indices for $SU(2)_{additional}$.
Then we apply Fermi statistics to say that we know upon swapping of the two quarks we should pick up a minus. Our representation for the strong force is known to already be antisymmetric upon swapping of the a index with b. So that means that the other indices must be symmetric upon swapping. I.e if we swap i with j and at the same time swap $\alpha$ with $\beta$ we should not pick up a minus. Therefore, there will be two possibilities for the other SU(2) symmetry groups. Either both are in their antisymmetric rep or both are in their symmetric rep.
So the we end up getting:

$Q^{ij \: ab \:\alpha\beta}= \lambda_1\epsilon^{ab}\epsilon^{ij}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta}+\lambda_2\epsilon^{ab}A^{ij \: \alpha \beta}$

where the A is a tensor that is symmetric upon swapping of i with j or alpha with beta.
In some different notation you could write it as:

$(\underline{2}_{SU(2)_l}\otimes\underline{2}_{SU(2)_l},\underline{2}_{SU(2)_q}\otimes\underline{2}_{SU(2)_q},\underline{2}_{SU(2)_a}\otimes\underline{2}_{SU(2)_a})=(\underline{1}_{SU(2)_l},\underline{1}_{SU(2)_q},\underline{1}_{SU(2)_a})\oplus(\underline{1}_{SU(2)_l},\underline{3}_{SU(2)_q},\underline{3}_{SU(2)_a})$

Edited to add: just saw you wanted the additional symmetry to be a quark lepton doublet. I'm unsure as whether my answer could provide that. However, I believe the rest of it still stands (like the fact a Baryon would be made up of two quarks instead of three).

Comment: Could you please revise your answer according to the new edition of the question?